# Are regular maps between degree $2$ curves in affine $2$-space just affine maps?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $K$ denote an arbitrary field. Let $X$ and $Y$ denote degree $2$ curves in affine $2$-space over $K$. Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ denote a regular map. Is it true that $f$ must be an affine transformation? If not, is this at least true when $K$ is a perfect field?

*Motivation.* I'm trying to get a basic working intuition for regular maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The map $(x,y) \mapsto (x^{-1},y^{-1})$ is not affine, but is a regular automorphism of the affine conic $1 = xy$.

For intuition it is already good to look the case where the target is the affine line $\Bbb A_K^1$. A regular map $f : X \to K$ is a quotient of polynomials functions $f/g$ so that $Z(g) \cap X = \emptyset$.

Comment: Okay, after a bit of thought, I'm not sure this is actually counterexample (admittedly my question wasn't that clear). In particular, define $f : (1 = xy) \rightarrow (1 = xy)$ as you state. Then $f$ can be described as the restriction of more than one rational function $\mathbb{A}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^2$. It can be described as a restriction of $(x,y) \mapsto (x^{-1},y^{-1})$. But it can also be described as a restriction of $(x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$. Is there a counterexample that can't be "reconceptualized" as an affine map like this?

Comment: @goblin : ah you are right, let me think a bit.

Comment: @goblin : ok here is a cheap example. Take $X : y=x^2$ and $Y : y^2 = x^2$, and the map $(x,y) \mapsto (x,y^2)$. If you want smooth conic you can take $y=x^2 +1$ and $y^2 = x^2 +1$.